# Gatsby warning: Plugin `gatsby-source-filesystem` tried to define the GraphQL type `File`

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to figure out what exactly triggers the following warning when I run "gatsby develop" or "gatsby build" command for my gatsby site.

[image]

I've tried googling around, and a fresh install of a new gatsby starter default and the problem still persists.

I'm assuming this warning is specific to Gatsby. If would be great if someone from the Gatsby team could explain what this warning is about.

Comment: What other plugins are you using?

Comment: This happens when you use an older version of gatsby-source-filesystem plugin alongside the current version of gatsby core.

This is a harmless warning but the solution is to upgrade to gatsby-source-filesystem@^2.1.41